# Make PayPal Payments - (send money) - API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to have "reversed store" so instead of accepting payments I want to SEND them. I am buying consumer electronic from my customers and I have admin panel so I want to create a PayNow button and I want to use PayPal API to send them payment, but I was not able to find any guide how to do that. Can somebody point me in right direction? Thanks !